# Is there a way to bulk assert in Junit5?

Tags: java, mockito, assert, junit5

This is my current Junit5 test script

```
Class testObject {
  private Integer integerField;
  private String stringField;
  private Boolean booleanField;

  ...getter, setter here
}
```

```
Class TestScript {
  private static final INTEGER DEFAULT_INTEGER_FIELD = 123;
  private static final STRING DEFAULT_STRING_FIELD = "string";
  private static final BOOLEAN DEFAULT_BOOLEAN_FIELD = false;

  private TestObject testObject;

  @BeforeEach 
  public void initTest{
    testObject.setIntegerField(DEFAULT_INTEGER_FIELD );
    testObject.setStringField(DEFAULT_STRING_FIELD );
    testObject.setBooleanField(DEFAULT_BOOLEAN_FIELD );
  }

  @Test
  public void saveShouldReturnTestObjectWithAllField() {
    //arrange
      ...

    //act
     TestObject savedObject = repository.save(testObject);

    //assert
    assertEquals(savedObject.getIntegerField(), DEFAULT_INTEGER_FIELD);
    assertEquals(savedObject.getStringField(), DEFAULT_STRING_FIELD);
    assertEquals(savedObject.getBooleanField(), DEFAULT_BOOLEAN_FIELD);

  }
```

This is a lot of typing especially an object have a lot of fields.

I am wondering is there any library or util class I can write to help me

1. auto instantiate my `testObject` and assign random values as default values to the `testObject`
2. assertEquals all fields in `testObject` with the default values

It will be so cool if we can

```
Class TestScript {

  private TestObject testObject;

  @BeforeEach 
  public void initTest{
    testObject = CustomAssertUtil.initDefault(testObject);
  }

  @Test
  public void saveShouldReturnTestObjectWithAllField() {
    //arrange
      ...

    //act
     TestObject savedObject = repository.save(testObject);

    //assert
    CustomAssertUtil.assertEqualsAllWithDefault(savedObject);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use Open Pojo: https://github.com/OpenPojo/openpojo

Comment: However, you shouldn't use random values in your unit tests. A test might only fail sometimes, and you'll have a very fun time trying to narrow down why. It's better to use a few standard cases and all the edge cases you can think of. If it passes on 5, it'll probably pass on 6. MAX_VALUE, MIN_VALUE, 0, and null? Those might have bugs